# Historical Membership Count reports based on Calendar Year

Tags: wordpress, civireport, reports, searchkit

We are using CiviCrm 5.65.1.

We would like to extract historical membership counts for certain time periods in the past say CAlendat  Year 2014, 2015 etc.

The typical membership status that we have are New, Current, Grace, Expired, Pending Cancelled, Deceased and Resigned.

New members join and have differing membership expiration dates.
One complication is that we have a membership category of "Life" with a membership expiration date of 2100 and in some cases blank.

Question - what would be the easiest way to obtain this count on a historical calendar basis.

Comment: @ Alan Dixon...many thanks I will have a look at this extension when I upgrade to 5.66 next week.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways of calculating historical membership numbers:

1. The membership dashboard uses the activities that are generated when a membership is created/renewed/expired.
2. The membership churn chart extension uses some sql based on just the membership records.

In the real world, neither of those are always the whole story, it depends on how you manage your memberships (e.g. restarted expired memberships, etc.)

I'd start with the churn chart extension, and take a look at the sql if the numbers look like what you want.